# Reliable email encoding

Tags: .net, email, encoding

What are the most reliable encodings for sending email? I had some problems recently with .NET's *System.Net.Mail* default of *quoted-printable* ('*=0D=0A*' scattered throughout the message).

So I changed to *iso-8859-1* for the body (set via alternative views), and *7bit* for transfer (and *base64* for embedded resources).

Are there the better choices?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choice yould be UTF-8. [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)